# How to force exit Django app when database connection fails

Tags: django, database, exit

I am trying to have django asgi app exit when the database connection fails. Normal behaviour seems to be that the app and its endpoint happily keep running and are accessible even though the database connection has failed. I want the app to exit. I tried this in asgi.py but the app still persists when I deliberately have the database connection to fail. Any ideas?

```
import os
import django
import threading
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.db import connections
from django.db.utils import OperationalError

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "SAFD.settings")
django.setup()

# Function to check database connection in a separate thread
def check_database_connection():
    try:
        connections['default'].cursor()
    except OperationalError:
        exit(1)
        # raise Exception("Database connection failed")

# Synchronously check the database connection
db_check_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_database_connection)
db_check_thread.start()
db_check_thread.join()

# Create the ASGI application instance
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

async def application(scope, receive, send):
    await django_asgi_app(scope, receive, send)
```

In fact right now I would dare to say that the error handling in Django is not set up correctly. If the app runs without the db connection, you can happily reach your endpoints but get errors like 'Network error' instead of what the real problem is: 'Database error'

Comment: The point is that this logic is normally part of a runner script, because it does not make sense of starting up a web server like gunicorn, apache/mod_wsgi, uwsgi, etc. when essential things are failing. It seems much better to have a "run.sh" or something similar that does the tests before given control to de web server. OTOH, a database server may fail temporarily and it may not be necessary to shut down the web app.

Comment: Yeah the thing we don't get to run a runner script, the whole Django app is supposed to be run inside an Azure function app, which only hooks to the asgi (or wsgi) application... Is a middleware something? But how do a exit the whole Django app. sys.exit() does not do the trick